# How to install the tkz-euclide package to use with Miktex?

Tags: formatting

I use Miktex 2.02, 64 bit. When I compile (Latex - PDF)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fourier}

\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,svgnames]{xcolor}

\usepackage{tikz}

\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetkzobj{all} 

\usepackage[portuguese]{babel}

\begin{document}

\begin{tizpicture}[scale=.8]

\tkzSetUpLini[color=blue!80]

\begin{scope}[rotate=30]

\tkzDefPoint(2,30){A}

\tkzDefPoint(90:5){B}

\tkzDefPoint(30:6){C}

\end{scope}

\tkzDrawPolygon(A,B,C)

\tkzLabelPoints[above](B,C)

\tkzLabelPoints[below](A)
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

the message appears:

[image]

Comment: is it a typo that it says `tz`?

Comment: And MiKTeX `2.02`?

Comment: remind me why is this now being closed ?

Comment: With the reputations shown, the OP should be able to find the typos and correct them after 2 comments issued but the OP did not notice the follow-ups. Further, an update is a logical move to check before asking. With that said, it is my view that the quality of the question is not recommended. Thus agreed to close it.

Comment: tz ??? Like percusse remarks it's perhaps or surely a typo : `tkz-euclide` instead of tz-euclide!

Answer (score 3):

Use `MiKTeX Package Manager` : select package, right-click and choose `install` in the pop-up menu:

[image]